# How can I pass a NSString parameter to a function?

Tags: objective-c

I want to initialize an object. The problem is how to pass the NSString correctly.

Object code:

```
#import "ClaseHoja.h"

@implementation ClaseHoja

@synthesize pares;
@synthesize nombre;

-(id)init
{
    self=[super init];
    if(self){

    }
    return self;
}
-(id)initWithValues:(NSString*)nom par:(int)par
{
    if([super init]){
        pares=par;
        nombre=nom;

    }
    return self;
}
```

When I call the function I do this:

```
 NSString *nombre="Hello";
 int par=20;
 ClaseHoja *ch = [ClaseHoja alloc] initWithValues:nombre par:numPares]];
```

Comment: Please find a more up-to-date tutorial. The use of `@synthesize` is obsolete in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest:

1. Add the missing `@` to `@"Hello"` and fix the `[]` in your `alloc`/`init` call.
2. If you're using Xcode, I'd let the compiler synthesize the properties for you. No `@synthesize` is needed. If you're using a stand-alone LLVM on some other platform, though, you might need it, but by convention, you'd specify an ivar with a preceding `_`.
3. I'd define `nombre` to be `copy` property and explicitly copy the `nombre` value passed to your `init` method. You don't want to risk having a `NSMutableString` being passed to your method and having it unwittingly mutated without your knowledge.
4. I'd suggest renaming the `initWithValues:par:` to be `initWithNombre:pares:`, to eliminate any doubt about what properties are being updated.
5. You don't need `init` without parameters. You can just rely on the one provided by `NSObject`.
6. You'd generally use `NSInteger` rather than `int`.
7. In your custom `init` method, you want to make sure to do `if ((self = [super init])) { ... }`

Thus:

```
// ClaseHoja.h

@import Foundation;

@interface ClaseHora: NSObject 

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *nombre;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger pares;

- (id)initWithNombre:(NSString*)nombre pares:(NSInteger)pares;

@end
```

And

```
// ClaseHoja.m

#import "ClaseHoja.h"

@implementation ClaseHoja

// If you're using modern Objective-C compiler (such as included with Xcode), 
// you don't need these lines, but if you're using, for example stand-alone 
// LLVM in Windows, you might have to uncomment the following lines:
//
// @synthesize nombre = _nombre;
// @synthesize pares = _pares;

- (id)initWithNombre:(NSString*)nombre pares:(NSInteger)pares {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        _pares = pares;
        _nombre = [nombre copy];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

And you'd use it like so:

```
NSString *nombre = @"Hello";
NSInteger pares  = 20;
ClaseHoja *ch = [[ClaseHoja alloc] initWithNombre:nombre pares:pares];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass like this. Another thing you miss `@` sign before the string.

```
NSString *nombre = @"Hello"; int par=20;
ClaseHoja *ch = [[ClaseHoja alloc]initWithValues:nombre par:par];
```

Comment: There's an extra `]` at the end.

Comment: Yes, Thank you. Edited.